# Swift #define in Extension

Tags: swift

How can i define a Constant in a Extension analogous to Objective C

Objective C:

```
#define integerMax NSIntegerMax
```

Swift:

```
extension NSMutableArray {
      let integerMax = Int.max  // Doesn't work
```

Comment: You are confusing preprocessor directives and stored properties (which you cannot add in class extension).

Comment: Yeah, this is rather confusing code. The ObjC code doesn't even mention NSMutableArray, why would the Swift code mention it?

Answer (score 6):

You can add it as a (readonly) computed property:

```
extension NSMutableArray {
    var integerMax : Int { get { return Int.max } }
    ...
}
```

see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25428013/2274829

**Edit**

A more concise version, as suggested in the comments:

```
extension NSMutableArray {
    var integerMax : Int { return Int.max }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not possible. `Extensions may not contain stored properties.`

Comment: True that Swift extensions may not contain stored properties but a read-only computed property is functionally equivalent to a constant stored property.

Comment: I suggest the more concise syntax `var integerMax: Int { return Int.max }`. If a stored property has only a getter then the `get` keyword and braces are not required.

Answer (score 1):

you can define first the constant. And then using it in the extension

```
let integerMax = Int.max
extension NSMutableArray {
    func someFunc() {
        var someVar : Int = integerMax
        //..... 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume Extensions have the same constraint as Categories in Obj-C in that you can't add new instance variables (or in this case constants).

the #define in Obj-C is not the same as a let-generated constant in Swift.
 #define is a preprocessor macro which simply tells the compiler to do a find and replace on the name with the value.
the let statement is in effect creating a new property on the class which you can't do in Extensions/Categories.

In Obj-C you can route around this with associated objects by using some runtime magic. I'm afraid I don't know the equivalent for Swift or even if it's possible.