# Can I extend a final class in Swift?

Tags: swift, class-extensions, final-class

I'm using a third-party library for a new app that I'm making using Swift. The author of the class/library has made it final using the `final` keyword, probably to optimise and to prevent overriding its properties and methods.

Example:

```
final public class ExampleClass {
   // Properties and Methods here
}
```

Is it possible for me extend the class and add some new properties and methods to it without overriding the defaults?

Like so:

```
extension ExampleClass {
    // New Properties and Methods inside
}
```

Answer (score 7):

An extension may not contain stored properties but you can add methods inside.

Answer (score 5):

Extensions (like Objective-C categories) don't allow stored properties.
Methods and computed properties are fine though.

A common (but IMO hacky) workaround in Objective-C was to use [associated objects](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/) to gain storage within categories. This also works in Swift if you `import ObjectiveC`.
This answer contains [some details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32061229/100848).

Comment: Let's remind that it only works for associating `NSObject` subclasses.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can extend a final class.
That extension has to follow the usual rules for extensions, otherwise it's nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot create new stored properties in extensions you can add *methods* and *computed properties*.

Example computed property:

```
extension ExampleClass { 

  // computed properties do not have a setter, only get access
  var asInt: Int? { 
    Int(aStringPropertyOnTheClass) 
  }
}
```