# Swift extension storage for protocols

Tags: swift

I make a protocol:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func getData() -> String
}
```

I make a struct that conforms to it:

```
struct SomeStruct: SomeProtocol {
    func getData() -> String {
        return "Hello"
    }
}
```

Now I want every `UIViewController` to have a property called `source`, so I can do something like…

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.title = source.getData()
    }
}
```

To accomplish this, I create a protocol to define the property:

```
protocol SomeProtocolInjectable {
    var source: SomeProtocol! { get set }
}
```

Now I just need to extend the view controller with this property:

```
extension UIViewController: SomeProtocolInjectable {
    // ???
}
```

How can I hack together a stored property that will work with a protocol type?

What hasn't worked:

- `var source: SomeProtocol!` obviously doesn't work because extensions don't have stored properties
- I can't [use Objective-C associated objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25428013/1445366) because a protocol isn't an object
- I can't [wrap it in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29662314/1445366) (this does work for other value types, but not protocols)

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Will using a static property work for you?

Comment: That's a good workaround, but ideally different view controllers would have different `source`s. If you want to leave it as an answer, I'll accept it in a day or two if nothing better comes along.

Comment: See my answer below - you can achieve different `source` per instance using some *proxy* type...

Comment: Do you necessarily need to extend `UIViewController`, `MyViewController` would suffice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any protocol object can be converted into a type-erased class. Build an `AnySomeProtocol` and store that.

```
private var sourceKey: UInt8 = 0

final class AnySomeProtocol: SomeProtocol {
    func getData() -> String { return _getData() }
    init(_ someProtocol: SomeProtocol) { _getData = someProtocol.getData }
    private let _getData: () -> String
}

extension UIViewController: SomeProtocolInjectable {
    var source: SomeProtocol! {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &sourceKey) as? SomeProtocol
        }
        set(newValue) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &sourceKey, AnySomeProtocol(newValue), .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }
}

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.title = source.getData()
    }
}
```

The caller can only use this to access the protocol methods. You can't force it back into its original type with `as`, but you should avoid that anyway.

As a side note, I'd really recommend making `source` return `SomeProtocol?` rather than `SomeProtocol!`. There's nothing here that promises that `source` will be set. You don't even set it until `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, this copies the state from whatever implemented `SomeProtocol`. But aside from that, wouldn't this effectively replace a `SomeStruct` with an `AnySomeProtocol`? `SomeStruct` will have different implementation. For example, one type might get data from a web service, but another from Core Data.

Comment: This doesn't copy the state. It forwards to the struct's implementation. _getData isn't a String. It's a function that returns a String. Even though the struct is inaccessible, the closure captures the struct (or captures whatever else you pass that implements this protocol). This is very much like AnySequence or AnyGenerator in the stdlib. See http://robnapier.net/erasure

Comment: Thanks! Wonderful blog post too.

Comment: BTW, I'm using `SomeProtocol!` on purpose: I want the app to crash as soon as possible if I forget to set `source` somewhere. But generally I agree with you about avoiding implicitly unwrapped optionals.

Comment: @RobNapier This answer is a little old.  Have you modified this approach at all?

Comment: @BrodyRobertson No.

Answer (score 5):

You can hack around with a static and the view controllers `hash`:

```
struct SomeProtocol {/*....*/}

struct DataProxy {
    var data: [Int: SomeProtocol]
}



protocol SomeProtocolInjectable {
    var source: SomeProtocol! { get set }
}

extension UIViewController: SomeProtocolInjectable {

    static var dataProxy = DataProxy(data: [:])

    var source: SomeProtocol! {
        get{
            return UIViewController.dataProxy.data[self.hashValue]
        }
        set{
            UIViewController.dataProxy.data[self.hashValue] = newValue
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that this relies on undocumented behavior. It happens to work because UIViewController implements hash by returning its address pointer, but that isn't promised. Two view controllers are permitted to have the same hash (they just probably won't). Instead you could index on the pointer to the object: `Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()` (which is a valid dictionary key, but the pointer is completely unsafe to use). Note that this approach never frees the stored data, even after the view controller is destroyed.

Comment: Clever! But I agree with @RobNapier, I'd like to avoid counting on the undocumented hashing behavior. +1 for creativity though.

Answer (score -2):

How about adding a default implementation for `getData()`, having a dummy struct implementation for the protocol, and use that as a default value for the `source` variable:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func getData() -> String
}

extension SomeProtocol {
    func getData() -> String {
        return "Hello"
    }
}

protocol SomeProtocolInjectable {
    var source: SomeProtocol { get set }
}

struct DummyProtocolImplementation: SomeProtocol {

}

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    var _source: SomeProtocol = DummyProtocolImplementation()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.title = source.getData()
    }
}

extension MyViewController: SomeProtocolInjectable {
    var source: SomeProtocol { get { return _source } set { _source = newValue } }
}
```

I took the liberty to extend `MyViewController` instead of `UIViewController`, as the latter doesn't know about the protocol anyhow.

Comment: This requires declaring a property on every view controller subclass, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Not if you inherit all your controllers from `MyViewController`