# Swift: Get extension variable inside itself

Tags: swift

For example, I have a var `a` and want to access it with a function:

```
extension SKNode {

    static var a = true

    func aaa() -> Bool {
        return self.a
    }

}
```

When I try this, it says "Static member 'a' cannot be used on instance of type SKNode"

Comment: Just remove `static`.

Comment: Then I get the error "Extensions may not contain stored properties"

Comment: What happens if you remove `self.` instead?

Comment: I get the same error that is showing on the question

Comment: I suggest googling both of the error messages you are getting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426780/swift-extension-stored-properties-alternative, for instance, might help.

Comment: I'll check it, thanks!

Comment: @SergioToledoPiza declare it as a computed property     `var a: Bool { return  true }`

Comment: thanks leo! and do you know what should I do to make it possible to be changed? like setting `myNode.a = false`

Comment: @SergioToledoPiza: please describe what you really want to do. Why are trying to add a new property to `SKNode`?