# how can I expand the hit area of a specific UIButton in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift3, extension-methods

In my application I have a `UIButton` that is quite small, so I thought about increasing the hit area of it.

I found an extension for that:

```
fileprivate let minimumHitArea = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)

extension UIButton {
    open override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        // if the button is hidden/disabled/transparent it can't be hit
        if self.isHidden || !self.isUserInteractionEnabled || self.alpha < 0.01 { return nil }

        // increase the hit frame to be at least as big as `minimumHitArea`
        let buttonSize = self.bounds.size
        let widthToAdd = max(minimumHitArea.width - buttonSize.width, 0)
        let heightToAdd = max(minimumHitArea.height - buttonSize.height, 0)
        let largerFrame = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: -widthToAdd / 2, dy: -heightToAdd / 2)

        // perform hit test on larger frame
        return (largerFrame.contains(point)) ? self : nil
    }
}
```

but when I use it, every button in my app has a bigger hit area. I want to increase it to only one `specialButton` - how can I do it?

Comment: An alternative to @ronatory's answer is to (1) subclass UIButton as, say,  `SpecialButton`, and then extend that instead of UIButton.

Comment: Note that overriding functions from an extension is a bad idea, and is not allowed in "pure" swift, only in Objective-C NSObject classes. To quote the Apple Swift iBook: “Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.0.1).” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Comment: Updated my answer. But unfortunately the method does not work like expected. I think you should try matt's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42182054/5327882

Comment: @ronatory thanks for your answer though, I really appreciate your effort :) The thing is I tried matt's answer and it doesn't seem to work well, I'm not sure what might be the problem there though

Answer (score 1):

Don't expand the hit area; shrink the drawing area. Make the button a subclass of UIButton, and in that subclass, implement `rect` methods, along these lines:

```
class MyButton : UIButton {
    override func contentRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: 30, dy: 30)
    }
    override func backgroundRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: 30, dy: 30)
    }
}
```

Now the button is tappable 30 points outside its visible background.

[image]

Comment: Currently my button has constraints set like this: http://imgur.com/a/T3p8x if I want to expand the touch area for e.g. 5 from each side, how should I do it? Do I have to change the `width` and `height` in constraints (by adding 5 to each of them) and then how could I change the `contentEdgeInsets`?

Comment: Sorry, my first answer didn't work, but my second answer does.

Comment: hmm @matt, I tried your approach, put this class as an outlet connection and also set it up in storyboard for my button, but it doesn't work well - currently the image from my button is gone... the button itself is clickable, but the area is not expanded for sure for 30px more each side :(

Comment: The clickable area is the size of the button. You said you have constraints so you will need to adjust those, obviously.

Comment: hm, so I changed the constraints now of my button to `width: 45` and `height:45`, then ran the app and the button changed size... what am I doing wrong? I expected the button to be the same size, but the clickable area grow around it... My button has a corner radius set up and it's round - maybe that causes some problems here?

Comment: I can't see what you're now doing. But I assure you that what I describe works.

Comment: Added an animated gif showing that the button is tappable 30 pixels outside its visible boundary.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `computed property` to your extension which you can set in your controller if you want to enable the hit area like this:

```
fileprivate let minimumHitArea = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)

extension UIButton {

  var isIncreasedHitAreaEnabled: Bool {
    get {
      // default value is false, so you can easily handle from outside when to enable the increased hit area of your specific button
      return false
    }
    set {

    }
  }

  open override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    // if the button is hidden/disabled/transparent it can't be hit
    if self.isHidden || !self.isUserInteractionEnabled || self.alpha < 0.01 { return nil }

    // only if it's true the hit area can be increased
    if isIncreasedHitAreaEnabled {
      // increase the hit frame to be at least as big as `minimumHitArea`
      let buttonSize = self.bounds.size
      let widthToAdd = max(minimumHitArea.width - buttonSize.width, 0)
      let heightToAdd = max(minimumHitArea.height - buttonSize.height, 0)
      let largerFrame = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: -widthToAdd / 2, dy: -heightToAdd / 2)

      // perform hit test on larger frame
      return (largerFrame.contains(point)) ? self : nil
    }
    return self
  }
}
```

And then in your view controller just set `isIncreasedHitAreaEnabled` to `true` if you want to increase it for a specific button (e.g. in your `viewDidLoad`):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  specialButton.isIncreasedHitAreaEnabled = true
}
```

**Update:**

First of all the method which you use doesn't work like expected. And also my approach with the `computed property` did not work like I thought. So even if the method does not work like expected, I just want to update my approach with the `computed property`.
So to set the property from outside, you can use [Associated Objects](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/). Also have look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25428013/5327882). With this solution now it would be possible to handle the `Bool` property `isIncreasedHitAreaEnabled` from your controller:

```
fileprivate let minimumHitArea = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
private var xoAssociationKey: UInt8 = 0

extension UIButton {

  var isIncreasedHitAreaEnabled: Bool {
    get {
      return (objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &xoAssociationKey) != nil)
    }
    set(newValue) {
      objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &xoAssociationKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    }
  }

  open override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    // if the button is hidden/disabled/transparent it can't be hit
    if self.isHidden || !self.isUserInteractionEnabled || self.alpha < 0.01 { return nil }

    if isIncreasedHitAreaEnabled {
      // increase the hit frame to be at least as big as `minimumHitArea`
      let buttonSize = self.bounds.size
      let widthToAdd = max(minimumHitArea.width - buttonSize.width, 0)
      let heightToAdd = max(minimumHitArea.height - buttonSize.height, 0)
      let largerFrame = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: -widthToAdd / 2, dy: -heightToAdd / 2)

      // perform hit test on larger frame
      return (largerFrame.contains(point)) ? self : nil
    }
    return self
  }
}
```

Comment: so let me get this right - if I don't set the flag `isincreasedHitAreaEnabled`, then it will be false by default? I mean - I do not need to set it to false on every other button in my app, right?

Comment: hmm, @ronatory, I think this code affected all buttons in my app, even though I set `isIncreased...` only on one of them... What is more, even if I change the `minimumHitArea` to `width:10, height:10`, it seems like the hit area covers the whole view - do you know what might be wrong here?

Comment: I will check it

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom UIButton Class and override pointInside:(CGPoint)point method like below. Then set these properties value from viewController.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CustomButton : UIButton
    @property (nonatomic) CGFloat leftArea;
    @property (nonatomic) CGFloat rightArea;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat topArea;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat bottomArea;
@end




#import "CustomButton.h
@implementation CustomButton

-(BOOL) pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGRect newArea = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x - _leftArea, self.bounds.origin.y - _topArea, self.bounds.size.width + _leftArea + _rightArea, self.bounds.size.height + _bottomArea + _topArea);

    return CGRectContainsPoint(newArea, point);
}
@end
```