# Is default implementation of a get-set variable possible in a protocol extension?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Is it possible to create a variable in a (default implementation of a) protocol? Specifically, I have a variable required by the protocol as:

```
protocol SearchHandlingDelegate: class {
    ...
    var lastSearchTerm: String { get set }
    ...
}
```

and was hoping to have a default implementation of it in a protocol extension as:

```
extension SearchHandlingDelegate {
    ...
    var lastSearchTerm: String {
        set { lastSearchTerm = newValue }
        get { return lastSearchTerm }
    }
    ...
}
```

But this is a bottomless recursive self-call loop… I could have it return the value of another variable, but then it’s not really going to be possible to do this via a default implementation of the protocol…

Comment: Extensions cannot add stored properties – you can however use Obj-C associated objects, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/25426780/2976878 (dupe?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide default implementations of get/set properties for computed values, but you can’t add storage to a type from an extension.