# Set a minimum rolling speed

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I have a ball, which I fire into the air:

[image]

And it is initialised like so:

```
func initBallNode() {
    // TODO: Create ball node
    ballNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball1") // Create a ball
    ballNode.zPosition = ZPositions.ball
    let offsetFromCorner: CGFloat = 20 // Offset from bottom-left of screen
    ballNode.position = CGPoint(x: frame.minX + ballNode.size.width / 2 + offsetFromCorner, y: frame.minY + ballNode.size.height / 2 + offsetFromCorner)
    ballNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ballNode.size.width / 2)
    ballNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    ballNode.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 1 // <-- Does not set a minimum-speed

    addChild(ballNode)
}
```

How can I reduce the **minimum speed/velocity** of the ball so that it rolls less and comes to a **complete stop** earlier?

Is there a physics property to handle this, without affecting the mass of the object (making it fall earlier)?

---

**If you have any questions, please ask!**

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the `friction` of the `physicsBody`. By default the friction is 0.2, but it can range between 0.0 and 1.0

Comment: Doesn't setting the friction to `1` make it roll as it should (rolling with the surface), and `0` just make it slide (and I am just trying to make it stop rolling earlier)? Does it make it _stop rolling_ earlier?

Comment: Currently, my ball gets slower and then there is a point where it appears still, but the position shows that it still rolls for another 5-10 seconds. I need to detect when it stops properly.

Comment: @George_E `friction` is the first thing I would try out. I'm not able to test the code, but I thought that increasing the friction would make it stop earlier...

Comment: Do I need to set the friction to one for the ball **and** the floor? Is it additive, or does it just pick the highest friction is SpriteKit?

Comment: what doe you mean the position shows that it rolls for another 5-10 seconds?  If you ball is not moving, and your position is moving, then you are not properly outputting the position

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I can see the ball still rolling for another 5 seconds, but at such a slow pace I want it to stop, therefore by setting a minimum.

Comment: Then just set the velocity to 0,0

Comment: @Knight0fDragon That's what I have done in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

**This is still not an answer. This has issues that still go along with it, described in the edit(s) below the original answer.**

---

Due to [stored properties in Swift extensions not being allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426780/how-to-have-stored-properties-in-swift-the-same-way-i-had-on-objective-c/25428013#25428013) (which results in a small bit in Objective-C), this was made quite a bit harder. However, after some research and testing, I have come up with the solution that works well for now:

```
import SpriteKit


// Key to access the stored properties
private var minimumSpeedAssociatedKey: UInt8 = 0

extension SKPhysicsBody {

    // Minimum speed for each node
    var minimumSpeed: CGFloat? {
        get { return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &minimumSpeedAssociatedKey) as? CGFloat }
        set(newValue) { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &minimumSpeedAssociatedKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN) }
    }

    // Update the speed for each node
    func updateSpeed() {
        guard let safeMinimumSpeed = minimumSpeed else {
            assert(false, "You have tried to update an object speed, without setting the minimum for the node: \"\(self.node?.description ?? "Unavailable")\".")
        }
        let currentSpeed = sqrt(pow(velocity.dx, 2) + pow(velocity.dy, 2))
        if currentSpeed < safeMinimumSpeed && currentSpeed > 0 {
            angularVelocity = 0
            velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        }
    }

}
```

Place that in a Swift file in your project. Then, you can set the minimum speed:

```
ballNode.physicsBody?.minimumSpeed = 30
```

Then, override the update function like so:

```
override func didFinishUpdate() {
    ballNode.physicsBody?.updateSpeed()
}
```

As a result, the ball now no longer rolls lower than a velocity of `30`, and it stops instead. The stop is still almost unnoticeable, as the ball before was just going extremely slowly over a 5-second period. This is the results I was looking for.

I hope this helps people, and if you found a better solution (or Apple adds a new property), please post your own answer. :)

---

**Edit 1:**

I have now got a varying terrain. However, this causes strange physics when the ball rolls back when it hits a hill. This is therefore not a fully solved issue.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Updated the answer. Thanks! I have looked at the image provided by Apple about when the updates occur, but how do I know which update to use?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Refering to [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjXrLS5_aHeAhVKyoUKHRmrAOkQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Farchive%2Fdocumentation%2FGraphicsAnimation%2FConceptual%2FSpriteKit_PG%2FIntroduction%2FIntroduction.html&psig=AOvVaw1DLuUAY2mlBwlODHumL5Zq&ust=1540570219512637), just to be clear.