# How to add parameters to UIViewController extension?

Tags: ios, swift

I've successfully created an extension on `UIViewController` that allows me to call a function that triggers a `UIView` to animate down. However instead of just a plain `UIView`, I want to improve on the extension so that it is it takes two parameters (`background color`, and `label text`) that are a subview on the `UIView` 'popupAlert?

```
extension UIViewController {

func showAlert() {
    let popupAlert = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -60, width: view.frame.width, height: 60))
    popupAlert.backgroundColor = UIColor.brandSuccess()
    let window = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!

    window.addSubview(popupAlert)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
        popupAlert.transform = .init(translationX: 0, y: 60)
    }) { (_) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 4, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            popupAlert.transform = .init(translationX: 0, y: -60)

        }, completion: { (_) in
            popupAlert.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have stored properties in Swift, the same way I had on Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426780/how-to-have-stored-properties-in-swift-the-same-way-i-had-on-objective-c)

Comment: There is no text in given method

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure where to put the text, it would be to be centered in the popupAlert UIView. Does that make sense?

Comment: it is a kinda extremely bad practice to alter (i.e. add / remove) the `UIWindow` instance's subviews directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
extension UIViewController {

    func showAlert(bgColor: UIColor, lblText: String) {
        let popupAlert = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -60, width: view.frame.width, height: 60))
        let popupLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 60))
        popupAlert.backgroundColor = bgColor
        popupLbl.text = lblText
        popupLbl.textColor = .green
        popupLbl.textAlignment = .center
        let window = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!

        popupAlert.addSubview(popupLbl)
        window.addSubview(popupAlert)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            popupAlert.transform = .init(translationX: 0, y: 60)
        }) { (_) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 4, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                popupAlert.transform = .init(translationX: 0, y: -60)

            }, completion: { (_) in
                popupAlert.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**call**

```
    showAlert(bgColor: .red, lblText: "testtttt")
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, but then how do I get the lblText appearing within the UIView?

Comment: @unicorn_surprise You should add a `UILabel` instance in `popupAlert`