# Apple Combine add TapPublisher to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, combine

Can I add a tap publisher to a UIView or UILabel? UIButton has tapPublisher built in. I tried making an extension, but extensions can't store properties.

Also, is it bad practices to try and use a tap publisher on anything that isn't a button?

```
    func bindViewModel() {
        cancellables = [
            continueButton.tapPublisher.sink { [unowned self] in
                viewModel.action
                    .send(.question)
            },
            headlineLabel.tapPublisher.sink {
                // Error: "Value of type 'UILabel' has no member 'tapPublisher'..."
            })
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually UIButton doesn't have it built in. I suggest you're using extension from [Building custom Combine publishers in Swift](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/building-custom-combine-publishers-in-swift/)

For the button it's pretty clear, inside you just subscribe to `.touchUpInside` action.

But with `UILabel` or `UIView` it's not that clear: you have to add your gesture recogniser, make sure that you won't add one more if you've already added it.

You can check `gestureRecognizers`, but there's still a chance that it's not yours `gestureRecognizer` you're trying to subscribe to. You can store yours in an [associated object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43056053/3585796), but this not the best solution in terms of performance.

For `UILabel` you also need to turn on `userInteractionEnabled`.

I'd say it's too much logic for an extension, but it's up to you.